# Null pointer exception at Difference.<init>(Solution.java:16)

Tags: java

I m passing an array to a constructer but it is giving error "constructor Difference in class Difference cannot be applied to given types - Difference difference = new Difference(a);"  according to the error actual and formal argument lists differ in length. why is that?

```
class Difference {
    private int[] elements;
    public int maximumDifference;

    Difference(int[] elementsArray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < elementsArray.length; i++) {
            elements[i] = elementsArray[i];
        }
    }
}

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] a = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        sc.close();

        Difference difference = new Difference(a);
    }
}
```

I have removed 'void' but now I am getting a null point exception. I am guessing that elements array in class Difference has been created, however, the elements in it are not or they may contain null. How can I solve the issue here?

The error looks like this-

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
         at Difference.<init>(Solution.java:16)
         at Solution.main(Solution.java:57)
```

Comment: You put the word `void` in what was presumably supposed to be a constructor declaration. Remove it.

Comment: `void Difference(int[] elementsArray)` is not a constructor. `Difference(int[] elementsArray)` is.

Comment: For the NPE, you can check my updated answer

Answer (score 4):

`void Difference(int[] elementsArray)` is not a constructor. A constructor has no declared return type. You need to change that to remove `void`:

```
class Difference {
    private int[] elements;
    public int maximumDifference;

    Difference(int[] elementsArray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < elementsArray.length; i++) {
            elements[i] = elementsArray[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not defining a constructor for your class.

The proper definition of constructor in Java is:

```
Difference(int[] elementsArray) {
    ...
}
```

The error you are seeing is due to the fact that classes get one default constructor with zero arguments. Since you didn't define any kind of constructor the compiler thinks that it should stick to the default one.

As for the *NullPointerException* you are getting.

```
private int[] elements
```

is not initialized. By default class member variables are set to null
 if they are objects and to their default values if they are primitives. In Java arrays are considered objects so you elements variable is null.

Here is the working code:

```
Difference(int[] elementsArray) {
    elements = new int[elementsArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < elementsArray.length; i++) {
        elements[i] = elementsArray[i];
    }
}
```